# How to access to variable property of different class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I separate my image class which handle the image select widget.  On my `main.dart` file, I just call in my image class to show the image field which is working fine. When I click the button to select image it open up my gallery and I can select the images.  However, I want to clear the images once the form is submitted.

From the `main.dart` class I want to access to the variable inside the image class that has the selected images, so I can empty that variable array.

My question, is how can I access to the selected images variable inside my image widget class from the `main.dart` ?

Here's a code from my image widget class file.

```
class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageInput({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageInput> createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  List<File> selectedImages = [];
  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Inside my `main.dart` file, I just add in the image class widget to show the image field for the user to click on it to select the images.

```
body: Column(
        children[      
      const SizedBox(height: 20),
      const ImageInput(),  //<---- image class widget
      const SizedBox(height: 50),
       ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await sendData();
                //clear the selected images here
              },
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
])
```

Comment: pass the selectedImages index from main.dart to ImageInput class. When the user submits the form that time you can pass that selected list to ImageInput class.

Comment: Why is the selectedImages var type list? Will your user select multiple images? Where will you save the images?

Comment: Yep, that's correct the user select multiple images.  The images will be send to AWS to store in a bucket.

Comment: You might be looking for state-management solution. You can try riverpod/bloc or just callback method.

Comment: Yep, I'm going with callback method solution.